# Como aplicar ciclo For para imprimir el valor de una lista de listas

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
def ordenes(rutinaContable):     
    from functools import reduce
    totales = list(map(lambda x: [x[0]]+ list(map(lambda y:y[1]*y[2] ,x[1:])),rutinaContable))
    print(totales)
    
    totales = list(map(lambda x: [x[0]] + [reduce(lambda y,z: round(y+z,2),x[1:])] ,totales))
    print(totales)
    
    totales = list(map(lambda x: x if x[1]>=600000 else [x[0], x[1]+25000 ],totales))
    print(totales)
    
    
    print('------------------------ Inicio Registro diario ---------------------------------')   

            for ()
     
    print('-------------------------- Fin Registro diario ----------------------------------')
    


rutinaContable = [
        [1201, ("5464", 4, 25842.99), ("7854",18,23254.99), ("8521", 9, 48951.95)],                     
        [1202, ("8756", 3, 115362.58),("1112",18,2354.99)],                    
        [1203, ("2547", 1, 125698.20), ("2635", 2, 135645.20), ("1254", 1, 13645.20),("9965", 5, 1645.20)],                    
        [1204, ("9635", 7, 11.99), ("7733",11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 390.95)]  
    ]

ordenes(rutinaContable)
```

Lo que quiero es hacer es un ciclo que me llame los siguientes ítems de la lista:

```
------------------------ Inicio Registro diario --------------------------------- 
La factura 1201 tiene un total en pesos de 962,529.33 
La factura 1202 tiene un total en pesos de 413,477.56 
La factura 1203 tiene un total en pesos de 443,859.80 
La factura 1204 tiene un total en pesos de 27,247.57 
-------------------------- Fin Registro diario ---------------------------------
```

Este seria el resultado que quiero conseguir, pero no se como plantearlo.
Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Usa un bucle for para iterar sobre cada factura, fabrica las cadenas que deseas usando cada factura, agregalas a una lista y finalmente usa el método [join](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para unir todas las cadenas de la lista con un salto de linea. Esta es la forma más simple de resolverlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En python, este tipo de lista también es considerado una matriz, por lo que la forma de hacerlo sería con 2 corchetes, de la siguiente manera: `list[j][k]`, donde "j" y "k" son valores que tú elijas. El valor "j" va a buscar un item de la lista grande como puede ser:  `[1201, ("5464", 4, 25842.99), ("7854",18,23254.99), ("8521", 9, 48951.95)]`. Después, el valor "k" se refiere al valor deseado dentro de la lista de "j", como puede ser `("5464", 4, 25842.99)`.
Después de tener esto claro, para hacer el bucle for, tendrías que poner el valor fijo en "k", que en este caso sería 1, y el itinerante donde he situado "j", que iría subiendo.

```
for i in range(len(totales)):
    factura = totales[i][0]
    valor_en_pesos = totales[i][1]
    print("La factura", factura, "tiene un total en pesos de", valor_en_pesos)
```

Este sería el código necesario. He puesto en el for que se repita la cantidad de veces que items haya en la lista en vez de un número fijo por si fuera necesario añadir valores. De esta manera no habría que cambiar el código.

Comment: Buen día,
Muchas gracias por la explicación tan clara.

Comment: como se hace eso, no tengo idea.